# Multiple baseUri in RAML?

Tags: raml

I am new to RAML and I have a basic question:

It is not possible to specify a set of alternative baseUri (only a single is allowed). Is there any alternative way to model multiple alternative installations of an API (e.g. for separate release-cycle environments)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I deal with this is by templating `baseUri`.

For JVM apps I use:

```
baseUri: ${baseUri}
```

and render the RAML file as a JSP.

For Ruby apps I use:

```
baseUri: <%= base_uri >
```

and render as ERB.

The value for `baseUri` is computed on the fly, based on the inbound request, so it's always matching the host / domain where it's deployed.

Comment: Nice! I guess the solution I provided would be valid for composing this property manually (i.e. contract-first style), while the method you specify is composing this property based on the actual implementation (i.e. deployment-first style).

Comment: Well I'm a proponent of contract-first, and I think RAML actually supports and encourages the contract-first approach very well. But fixing the value of `baseUri` to a predefined set would be too impracticable, especially when you do transient cloud deployments of integrated builds whose final URI is random (generated by the cloud provider).

Answer (score 8):

One way could be to use baseUriParameters and using an enum value for the different deployments.

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Some Service
version: 1
baseUri: https://{environment}/rest/v{version}/services/someservice
baseUriParameters:
  environment:
    description: Integration test, Acceptance Integration Test, Production
    enum: ["test-api.company.com","acc-api.company.com","api.company.com"]
```